# Add a background colour to one (or all) layers in a Photoshop document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a document with many layers and each layer contains some transparent pixels. I'm trying to replace the transparent pixels in each layer with the colour black, essentially adding a background to them.

I'm struggling. This doesn't seem like something that should be so tricky.

The only way I can do it is by converting to Smart Object, edit, new layer, fill black, save, then Rasterize. But I need to do this hundreds of times, so I'd like to find a way to do it that I can save as an Action.

Thank you.

- noob

[image: This is an example of what I'm working with]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm not sure I understand this question fully. Can't you just add a black filled background layer at the bottom of the layer stack?  Why do you need to fill each image individually with a black background?

Comment: You *could* merely create slices, then export the slices.. based upon the posted image, that black background (presumably a lower layer) would be included in the slice.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are already transparent, you can add a new layer to the bottom of your layer list and fill it with your background color.  Should be much easier than editing each image separately.

[image: Transparent object]

[image: add new empty layer]

[image: paint bucket fill]